# Url with two slashes when I try to execute an Action

Tags: url, tomcat, netbeans, struts2, action

I am learning Struts2 and Tomcat 8.0.9.0 with Netbeans 8.0.1 and have a problem that when I run an Action that is the url in the browser has two symbols /, such as:

```
(http://localhost:8084/RepresentantsApp//View/Login.action;jsessionid=F902CF301F9A5E8EF26F823603129F33?request_locale=ca)
```

so it shows me the following error because I guess I did not find the Action correctly:

HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for action name login.

the code in jsp is:

```
<s:url id="ca" action="Login">
   <s:param name="request_locale">ca</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{ca}">                        
   <s:text name='idiomaCatala.link'/>
</s:a>
```

I would appreciate guidance.

Comment: Please show all relevant configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When building url with the `s:url` tag you should exclude context path if the value is used with anchor `s:a` or `s:form` tags

```
<s:url id="ca" action="Login" includeContext="false">
   <s:param name="request_locale">ca</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{#ca}">                        
   <s:text name="idiomaCatala.link"/>
</s:a>
```